# Is it possible to determine whether a page is a page template by page_id in ajax call?

Tags: ajax, page-template

I'm looking for an answer for the asked question. The reason is I'd like to omit the need to use is_page_template() in WP ajax calls.

Best regards, Dan.

Comment: can you add more details. question is not clear .

Comment: It was clear enough for @Jacob Peattie :)

Comment: so now you have an answer, cheers. I need bit clarification thats why commented. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the page template of an arbitrary page by ID you can use `get_page_template_slug()`:

```
// Set $page_id somehow, probably getting it from AJAX request.

$template = get_page_template_slug( $page_id );

if ( $template === 'templates/about.php' ) {
    // Do something.
}
```